# Replace backslahes in the accented file path

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried to replace the backslahes in file path I got from Excel file:

```
path = "X:\Clients\BUT_Monétique Commerçant\2Gestion\4_Suivi\Suivi_Projet"
```

as follows:

```
path.gsub!("\\","/")
```

or

```
path.gsub!("\\","\\\\")
```

and no one worked. Any idea how to solve that. As you see, the URL contains some accented letters.

Comment: It probably _doesn't work_ because there is no pattern `"\\"` inside of your path string.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen you commonly write a quote just after one backslash and this works? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using the following to define `path`?

```
path = "X:\Clients\BUT_Monétique Commerçant\2Gestion\4_Suivi\Suivi_Projet"
```

That doesn't work, at least in Ruby 1.8.7. You need to either use single quotes, or double the backslashes to escape them.

However, once you do that, the following works for me:

```
irb(main):001:0>  path = 'X:\Clients\BUT_Monétique Commerçant\2Gestion\4_Suivi\Suivi_Projet'
=> "X:\\Clients\\BUT_Mon\303\251tique Commer\303\247ant\\2Gestion\\4_Suivi\\Suivi_Projet"
irb(main):002:0> path.gsub!("\\","/")
=> "X:/Clients/BUT_Mon\303\251tique Commer\303\247ant/2Gestion/4_Suivi/Suivi_Projet"
```

If that isn't working for you, can you paste the actual code that you are running, and the results that you get?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
path = 'X:\Clients\BUT_Monétique Commerçant\2Gestion\4_Suivi\Suivi_Projet'
path.gsub!("\\","/")
p path 
#=> "X:/Clients/BUT_Monétique Commerçant/2Gestion/4_Suivi/Suivi_Projet"
```

Alternately, you could just `split` on the backslashes and let Ruby's `File` class determine the filesystem-appropriate separator:

```
path = 'X:\Clients\BUT_Monétique Commerçant\2Gestion\4_Suivi\Suivi_Projet'
old_path = path.split("\\")
new_path = File.join(old_path)
p new_path
#=> "X:/Clients/BUT_Monétique Commerçant/2Gestion/4_Suivi/Suivi_Projet"
```